# Convert curl to JS fetch() with input paramters

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have an http API I'm currently querying via curl from the command line, and I want to call it via fetch() in my JS app for testing purposes.

My curl command looks like this:

```
curl -vvv -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/json" --data '{"keywords":["keyword1", "keyword2"], "limit": 10}' https://url.omitted
```

I want to fetch it like:

```
var queryURL = "https://url.omitted";
fetch(queryURL, {
  method: 'POST'
});
```

I'm working from the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch, but having trouble figuring out how to pass the keyword and limit params. I'd be grateful for some guidance. (And I'm open to using a request type other than fetch(), too.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your data using `body` attribute:

```
fetch("https://url.omitted", {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {"keywords":["keyword1", "keyword2"], "limit": 10}
    })
```

and if you would like to use another `HTTP Client`, [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is a good one.

Comment: Thank you. I was overcomplicating trying to format the body attribute.